# Cauchy Functions And Initial Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm having a hard time solving this problem.

$$x''+4x=t$$
$a)$Derivative the corresponding Cauchy fn.

$b)$Find the solution of the given equation to the I.C., $x(0)=0$, $x'(0)=0$

So the char. eq. is $r^2+4=0$, $r_1=2i$ and $r_2=-2i$. How can I write $x(t)$ as a function when the roots are complex?

For $b)$ I have no idea to solve it.

Any advice/solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x''+4x=t$$
When the roots are complex like $ r=a\pm bi$ then
:$$x(t)=c_1e^{at}\cos (bt)+c_2e^{at}\sin (bt)$$
So for your solution ($r=\pm 2i$) you have to write:
$$x(t)=c_1\cos (2t)+c_2\sin (2t)$$

For $b$ part of the question, you have to first solve the inhomogeneous DE. Try Undetermined coefficients method;
$$x_p(t)=at$$
Plug this in your DE and find the constant $a$. Then apply initial conditions you 're given.
$$x(t)=c_1\cos (2t)+c_2\sin (2t)+at$$

Apply intial conditions:
$$x(0)=c_1\cos (2*0)+c_2\sin (2*0)+a*0$$
$$0=c_1$$
Apply the second intial condition
$$x(t)=c_2\sin (2t)+at$$
Differentiate the apply initial condition.